# Keeping old version of Firefox while updating to new version

Tags: install, software, versions

On my OSx I want to be able to switch version of software I use.

Like right now I have Firefox 29, but I want to try firefox 32. is there a way I can download and install version 32 and keep the old one as well?

How such strategy can be implemented on all softwares ? This gives me leverage to switch to older version with ease..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older versions of Firefox can be found here:

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

There's [Multifirefox app](http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox), which can help switching profiles for several versions.

Installation:

```
brew cask install multifirefox
```

> MultiFirefox is a small launcher utility that allows you to run multiple versions of Firefox side-by-side.  It helps you set up multiple profiles (one or more for each version of Firefox), remembers your last launch preferences for easy launching, has auto-updating built in for when we make improvements, and is 100% open source, MIT licensed.

[image]

Comment: is their a version for cents of multifirefox ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz: what's "cents"?

Comment: aah sorry I mean CentOS !

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz: probably not. It's written in Obj-C.

Comment: I saw on the link you gave its python based so I can give it a try to compile for centos too thanks anyway cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I normally do this to try out the new version to see what they have broken in the new.

Firstly you need to rename the Application (I use Firefox29 etc) then you can install new.

NOTE There some potential problems, as there can be a conflict with some settings and Add-ons.
The safest way is to create a new profile by copying the old. There are detailed instructions on the Firefox site.

It is a little clumsy swapping versions as you have to select the correct profile before starting Firefox.

Comment: can you link me up to instruction for spectating profiles between both versions, I already got both versions working by renaming.

Comment: In the Terminal application, enter the following:
`/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -p`  see https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Comment: I discovered whether I launch this for v32 r ver 29 both can only use same profile by default unless we uncheck the option to automatically take the selected profile.